# Is there a way to debug the node pipelines by outputting the actual values flowing through?

Tags: node-editor

I'd love it if there was a "spy-glass" node that you could see the values along any connection between nodes. It would work best if there were a way to pause graph processing and give you manual control over iterating through the different input streams.

We have this sort of thing in BigData systems which work the same. Pause the stream, look at the values, or even log the values to a file with inputs and outputs.

Maybe a logging node would suffice.

Thoughts?

Comment: yep, would be very nice, but AFAIK there is no way doing this. There are some tools which show graphical "results" but not as values.

Answer (score 0):

I concur, there is no direct way to do it. All the more so as that for shader nodes, values are computed per vertex and represent a field and not a single value.

A workaround can be to visualize values in a certain range to at least verify that they are somewhat ok. The node setup below provides a solution. It can even be transformed into a group with min and max values as inputs to work faster.

The blue block is a dummy math function and the green block is the test setup.

[image]

Comment: That makes sense.  In your example, how did you arrive at 100 & -50 for the mult&add?

I'm trying to confirm my understanding of how things work. For example, I'd like to apply one texture node within the scale of another. So, for example, a voronoi at a scale of 10 with noise applied at scale of 1 in each of the cells from the voronoi.

It's been difficult confirming things are happening as I think they're happening.

Comment: The mult & add is just an example to get values a bit more complicated than just 0 to 1.
Actually, a texture factor output is always between 0 and 1. The color is obviously a (0-255,0-255,0-255) triplet. Thus you can figure out roughly the ranges of your combinations.
For your Voronoi and noise textures case, do you know the Node wrangler addon? You can quickly visualize a node output by pressing SHIFT+LMB. I use it all the time to debug.
Here is an explanation link that seems to fit with your case:
https://youtu.be/XTVWy4IIH3A?t=223

Comment: Thanks, @Jag JB, i'll check it out